# What is the point of cake?

Tags: airmech

I have a cake for an item. The description says that it gives me +100% Yummy Cake. The wiki says that there are several different types of cake, but they all do the same thing. Does having more Yummy Cake benefit me, or is it just a joke?

Comment: The point of cake is to motivate and deceive you.

Answer (score 1):

The Cake is a joke item. It doesn't actually influence game play, but it makes people who can't afford other items feel better because it takes up that equipment slot.

Answer (score 1):

It's a part of Quests which rewards Diamonds (in game currency)

Comment: This is good information. Would you expand on this to make it a better answer.